# GhostScript undefined glyp

Tags: ghostscript

I'm using gs 9.20 to merge some pdf documents into a single document

```
/usr/bin/gs9/bin/gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dRENDERTTNOTDEF=true -sOutputFile=/docs/merged.pdf
```

And I'm getting this error and have no idea how to resolve it.  Has anyone come across these types of errors?

> GPL Ghostscript 9.20: ERROR: Page 5 used undefined glyph 'g2' from
>   type 3 font 'PDFType3Untitled'

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the original file its not possible to be certain, but I would guess from the error that the file calls for a particular glyph in a font (PDFType3Untitled), and that font does not contain that glyph.

The result is that you get an error message (messages from the PDF interpreter which begin with ERROR, as opposed to WARNING, mean that the output is very likely to be incorrect).

You will still get a PDF file, and it may be visually identical with the original because, obviously, the original file didn't have the glyph either.

As for 'resolving' it, you need to fix the original PDF file,that's almost certainly where the problem is.

Please note that you are not 'merging' PDF files as I keep on saying to people, the original file is torn down to graphics primitives, and then a new file built from those primitives. You cannot depend on any constructs in the original file being present in the final file. A truly 'merged' file would preserve that, Ghostscript's pdfwrite device does not.

See [here](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/VectorDevices.htm#Overview) for an explanation.